# php y consulta query

Tags: php

yo tengo un formulario con el cual segun los datos que metas te sale la información de una base de datos. Mi problema es que si no meto ningún dato(no meto min1) me sale  toda la informacion, cuando me debería de salir un mensaje con "la tabla esta vacía que es lo que he puesto como condición. ¿Me podéis ayudar para saber que he hecho mal por favor ?

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>FormularioPDO4 para consultar en la Base de Datos eligiendo una tabla</title>
</head>

<body>
<p><h4>Los articulos con un precio mayor o igual a este son:</h4></p>

    <?php

include("datosconexion.php");


$gd= new PDO($dsn,$usuario,$contrasena);


$min1=$_POST['min1'];


$consulta= "SELECT * FROM articulo WHERE :min1<=pvp";

$resultadoConsulta = $gd->prepare($consulta);
$resultadoConsulta->bindParam(':min1', $min1);


$ok=$resultadoConsulta->execute();

if($ok) {
    if($resultadoConsulta->rowcount()!=0){

        $n=$resultadoConsulta->columnCount();

        foreach($resultadoConsulta as $fila){

            echo"<p>";

            for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++){
                echo $fila[$i],"&nbsp","&nbsp","\t";
            }
            echo "</p>";
        }

    }else{
         echo "La tabla esta vacia";
    }
}
else echo "Error en la consulta";

$gd=null;
?>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Si no metes ningún dato, la variable $min1 puede valer cadena vacía o null (dependiendo del contexto en el que estés). Te sugiero que hagas la comprobación del valor de la variable antes de hacer la consulta y si no tiene un valor, directamente ni la hagas: simplemente muestres el mensaje correspondiente al error.

Answer (score 1):

Te he puesto un comentario al respecto, pero te lo extiendo un poco:

```
/* Usamos un operador ternario para determinar si existe la variable que,
en principio, debería llegar por $_POST desde el formulario que mencionas.
Como no citas el tipo de campo, si es un checkbox o radio button podría no 
llegar, si el usuario no marca una casilla o botón). 
Por lo tanto, lo primero, es estar seguros de que tenemos esa variable en 
$_POST.
Si no la tenemos, le damos, por defecto, un valor como cadena vacía. */    
$min1 = (isset($_POST["min1"])?$_POST["min1"]:"";

if ($min1 > "") // Si el valor de $min1 tiene algo que sea más que una cadena vacía
{
    // Hacemos la consulta
} else { / Si era un cadena vacía
    // No hacemos la consulta y mostramos un mensaje de notificación
}
```

Si he entendido correctamente tu pregunta, con esto lo resolvemos.

Comment: no se entiende tu respuesta

Comment: Vale con lo que me has dicho ya esta , muchísimas gracias

Comment: He añadido algunos comentarios para aclararla. Espero que sea más comprensible. Gracias a shadow por ayudarnos a mejorar y ponernos más en el lugar de quien pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Veo unos cuantos problemas con tu código, algunos son de lógica, otros de sintaxis, otros de optimización.

Los enumero brevemente por orden de aparición:

- Si la consulta depende de si hay POST o no, debes supeditar el `include` y la creación de la instancia de conexión a esa validación, de lo contrario estarás usando recursos sin siquiera saber si vas a necesitarlos. Es un error de optimización y de buenas prácticas.
- Para evaluar el POST es preferible usar `empty`. No te llenará el log de mensajes en caso de intentar buscar una clave que no exista. Aquí se usa un ternario con `empty` para evaluar el dato y guardarlo en una variable.
- La consulta como estaba no es correcta. Los marcadores de `:nombre` no se aplican sobre nombres de columnas, sino sobre valores. Lo que sustituye el marcador es el valor, no la columna.
- En el `SELECT` conviene nombrar las columnas de forma explícita. Evitarás seleccionar columnas que no necesites y recurrir luego a oscuros procedimientos para mostrar los datos. Para cualquier futuro programador que no seas tú y necesite revisar tu código, el procedimiento que usas para mostrar cada columna le resultará oscuro, incomprensible... porque no se llaman las cosas por su nombre. incluso tú misma, cuando revises ese código, pasado un tiempo, sabrás con exactitud qué es lo que se está imprimiendo. NÓTESE  que he usado dos columnas (imaginarias) que son `nombre` y `tipo` para dar claridad al código. Debes cambiarlas por las columnas reales que necesitas. También he usado `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` para recuperar los valores de cada columna por su nombre.
- Durante todo el código he usado una variable `$html` que será la encargada de ir guardando los resultados obtenidos. Al final se imprime esa variable.
- He trasladado el título `Los artículos con un precio mayor...` al lugar que le corresponde en la lógica del programa. Ese título no debería mostrarse en caso de no encontrar filas en la consulta.

El código propuesto es este, espero que sea de utilidad y sirva para aclarar conceptos e implementar buenas prácticas de programación:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>FormularioPDO4 para consultar en la Base de Datos eligiendo una tabla</title>
    </head>

    <body>

    <?php
    $min1=( empty($_POST['min1']) ) ? NULL : $_POST['min1'];

    if ( $min1 ) {
        /*
            Gestionamos la conexión aquí
            porque estamos seguros de que se necesitará
        */
        include("datosconexion.php");
        $gd= new PDO($dsn,$usuario,$contrasena);
        /*
            1. Aquí había un error, el marcador de :nombre es para el valor, 
               no para el nombre de la columna
               Si la columna se llama pvp cámbialo a la izquierda
            2. Conviene poner en el SELECT las columnas específicas que necesita
               así evitas procedimientos complicados como contar luego el total de columnas
               y además no seleccionas columnas que no necesites
               Aquí pongo como ejemplo dos columnas: nombre, tipo... 
               debes poner en el SELECT los nombres reales de tus columnas
        */
        $consulta= "SELECT nombre,tipo FROM articulo WHERE min1<=:min1";
        if ( $resultadoConsulta = $gd->prepare($consulta) ) {
            $resultadoConsulta->bindParam(':min1', $min1);
            if ($ok=$resultadoConsulta->execute() ){
                if($resultadoConsulta->rowcount()!=0){
                    $html="<h4>Los artículos con un precio mayor o igual a este son:</h4>";
                    while ($fila = $resultadoConsulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                        /*
                            Aquí asignamos las columnas ESPECÍFICAS del SELECT
                            por favor actualiza con los nombres reales de tus columnas
                        */
                        $nombre=$fila["nombre"];
                        $tipo=$fila["tipo"];
                        $html.="<p>$nombre&nbsp&nbsp\t$tipo</p>";
                    }
                } else {
                    $html.="La tabla esta vacía";
                }
            } else {
                $html.="Error ejecutando la consulta";
            }
        } else { 
            $html.="Error preparando"; 
        }
        $gd=null;       
    } else {
        $html.="No se posteó min1";
    }
    echo $html;
?>
    </body>
</html>
```